# Как узнать размер изображения

Tags: php, изображения

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы при загрузке аватарки (изображения) меньше 200x200 выбивало ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

[`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php) возвращает массив значений, в котором `[0]` и `[1]` - высота картинки:

```
<?php
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    if($size[0]<200 or $size[1]<200){
        // выводим ошибку
    }
```